# How to Fix vulnerability at Manifest.xml file in Android for an exposed component

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sonarqube, android-manifest

I need to expose a module of my app to more than one app. Since, I did not specify any permission or expose attribute of the activity.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
</activity>
```

With this, I can able to launch the application and i can able to do activity from other application too by calling intent.

But, When I integrate with SonarQube, its showing vulnerability and stating below issue.

> Implement permissions on this exported component.

To fix this issue, I have tried following method.

1. If I implement the permission to refer, vulnerability removed but I cannot able to run the application (I meant cannot place able to any actions from other app).

In my app, I have defined the permission

```
<permission android:name="com.myApp.NORMAL_PERMISSION"
    android:description="@string/perm_desc_NORMAL_PERMISSION"
    android:label="@string/perm_label_NORMAL_PERMISSION"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

and I refer this permission to my activity as below.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="com.myApp.NORMAL_PERMISSION"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
```

But, I cannot able to do any action from other app by calling intent. But, vulnerability has been fixed.

2. If I add the below field to activity still its listed under vulnerability android:exported= "true"
3. if its android:exported= "false", vulnerability removed but app completely is not working

Let me know any other method to fix this vulnerability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my main activity which hash intent-filter action android.intent.action.MAIN and category android.intent.category.LAUNCHER.

Its intended to be launched from other applications without any special permissions.

So, its require no permission.

```
<activity
    . . .
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="" >
```

That being said defining the permission as empty string resolves the issues and explicitly shows your intent that there are no permissions needed to launch this activity.